# iOS 6.0 Facebook SDK permissions, can't get gender of the user

Tags: facebook, permissions, ios6

I have quick question:

this code snippet works:

```
 NSArray *permissions = @[@"email", @"user_birthday"];
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                              allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState state,
                                                             NSError *error) {
                                             [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                                 state:state
                                                                 error:error];
                                         }];
```

And this doesn't:

```
NSArray *permissions = @[@"email", @"user_birthday", @"gender"];
return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                          allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState state,
                                                         NSError *error) {
                                         [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                             state:state
                                                             error:error];
                                     }];
```

I'm simply asking for the gender of the Facebook user and in first case I've got on my NSLog console: User session found which is great... but when I extend the permission and include gender in it, I've got UIAlertView with:
Error
The operation couldn't be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)

What I am doing wrong? How to ask for permission to get user gender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [list of permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/#permissions) - `gender` is not one of them - gender is, however a field of the [User object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) and is also exposed in the `sex` column in the [`user` FQL table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) which you can access once the user has granted you the basic permission to access their data.

A sample query (SDK agnostic) to return just the current user's gender is simply 
`/me?fields=gender`, the return value of which will be

```
{
  "gender": "male", 
  "id": "533875325"
}
```

Note that it's also returned in the default response when accessing a user, so you don't need to specify it explicitly.

Also, some users may not have a gender defined (though i think this is relatively rare)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/basic-info/), the gender is part of the basic informations.
And whenever you open a session with permissions, it will ask for basic informations.
Since you already have it, facebook musts consider it as an error.

I had the same issue when asking for the username by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Gender is not a public property of , so, you can't access using user.gender, as you do with user.name, here you have a dictionary and you access passing the Key.

like:

```
_genderLabel.text = [user objectForKey:@"gender"];
```

Cheers